# Problems with Tomcat 8 running as a service on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-services, tomcat8

I'm facing this issue when running Tomcat 7 and 8 (64bits) on windows as a service.

This is the error I'm facing: (on /log/commons-daemon.log)

```
[2015-06-11 17:03:37] [info]  [ 2744] Starting service...
[2015-06-11 17:03:37] [error] [ 2744] Failed creating java C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\client\jvm.dll
[2015-06-11 17:03:37] [error] [ 2744] The system cannot find the path     specified.
[2015-06-11 17:03:37] [error] [ 2744] ServiceStart returned 1
[2015-06-11 17:03:37] [error] [ 2744] The system cannot find the path     specified.
[2015-06-11 17:03:37] [info]  [ 2848] Run service finished.
[2015-06-11 17:03:37] [info]  [ 2848] Commons Daemon procrun finished
```

It's weird since I can run the server on command line.
Environment varialbes JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_HOME are set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem is related with Java Virtual Machine, we need to install version x64 if Apache version is x64.
On the Apache Gui configuration, tomcat8w (folder apache-tomcat-8.0.23\bin)

That solved the problem of staring tomcat as a service.